# Identify geographic location to points

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, point-in-polygon

I am quite new in QGIS and I really need your help.

I have a map of Kenya divided into 68 districts and I have coordinates of 30.000 schools. The points have one variable besides the latitude and longitude data called "distance to nearest school".

First I imported the map. Then I imported the spreedsheet and transformed it to a SHP file like the map. So now I have two SHP files.

The points have three variables: "Latitude", "Longitude" and "Distance to nearest school". I want to have a fourth variable called "District" and take the mean of the "Distance to nearest school" for each district.

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Are the two shapefiles in the same Coordinate Reference System? Have you tried importing the two shapefiles into QGIS? Do they "look right"?

Comment: Yes, they "look right". I mean, the points are located over the correct geographic areas on the map of Kenya.

Comment: So break it down into two stages - first find out which district, then do the averaging. There is a tutorial at http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-spatial-analysis-points-in.html that shows the sort of operation you need for the first part.

Comment: I have tried the link you sent. The thing is, it only counts the number of points within each district. My problem is for each point to create a new column which identifies the district. I hope it makes sense. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do a spatial join between your points and your districts: vector > data management tool > join attribute by location. There is a detailed tutorial on [this page](http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/join_spatial.php)

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a charm.
Also thanks to you BradHards :)